# How to propagate a grandparent relationship throughout a tree?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I've got a MySQL table with columns `id` and `parent`, wherein each row has another row as a parent, except for some special root rows with `parent=0`. There are no cycles or broken relations.

In order to cache which root row each row is associated with, I decided to add an `ancestor` column. My current plan is to build the tree in some other programming language, find all ancestors recursively and then update the table.

However, I'm convinced that there's a clever way to do this in SQL, requiring not more queries than the depth of the three. Could someone help me design this?

There are ~1000 rows and the depth is ~5, so performance is not really an issue.

Comment: Your tag says `sql-server`, your text says `MySQL`. Which one is it?

Comment: @Remus: Sorry, I wrote "sql" and it seems to have been auto-completed. I'm on MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim you have come to the right place.

It just so happens that I answered a question like this ( [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)  ) back in Oct 24, 2011.

I wrote Stored Procedures that traverse a table with id and parent fields. I also included sample data.

However, you may not have to resort to the Stored Procedures.

Here is what I mean: Let's start with the sample data

```
USE junk 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pctable; 
CREATE TABLE pctable 
( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    parent_id INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM; 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) VALUES (0); 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+1 FROM pctable; 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+2 FROM pctable; 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+3 FROM pctable; 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+4 FROM pctable; 
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+5 FROM pctable; 
SELECT * FROM pctable;
```

To reach any grandparent, you could just perform a JOIN of the pctable against itself:

```
SELECT P.id,GP.parent_id FROM pctable P
INNER JOIN pctable GP ON P.parent_id = GP.id;
```

To reach any great-grandparent, you could just perform a JOIN of the pctable against itself twice:

```
SELECT P.id,GGP.parent_id FROM pctable P
INNER JOIN pctable GP ON P.parent_id = GP.id;
INNER JOIN pctable GGP ON GP.parent_id = GGP.id;
```

Since your depth is no more than three, doing these JOINs should be quite enough.

Comment: Thank you, a neat and simple solution! I kept thinking I'd have to solve the general case, but that'd be completely unnecessary.