# Hierarchical queries without CTEs

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I'm new to MySQL. The `GetFamilyTree(id)` function that Rolando suggested in the [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes) question was great but when the id is greater than 999 it hangs.

Is there a solution that works with larger ids?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do

## THING #1

Expand all `VARCHAR(1024)` to `VARCHAR(10240)` in all Stored Procedures. This will accommodate longer Family Tree Listings. This is vital because `queue_children` can grow longer and longer if you have a lopsided tree structure. It also possible that when queue_children was 1024 in length and did not delimit properly, it probably went into some infinite loop trying to terminate properly and never reached the condition when the `LENGTH(queue_children)` would be 0.

## THING #2

[**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html)'s maximum  length is limited by group_concat_max_len (default is 1024). Try expanding [**group_concat_max_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to something ridiculously large (5000000000).

## THING #3

Increase your [**thread_stack**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack), perhaps 512K or 1M. This is needed for Stored Procedures with either recursive operations or, in this case, longer local variables to make room for.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed the part `"FORMAT(queue,0)"` into simply `"queue"`, GetFamilyTree worked for `IDs` over 999. This is because `FORMAT(9999,0) = "9,999"` in my system at least.

I also added a unique index under `id` and a non-unique index under `parent_id` and the code works well on a dataset with 230k rows. I also changed VARCHAR(1024) to TEXT.