# How to sort category by path and sort order?

Tags: mysql

first of all I am sory for my english.

My category structure is shown below. My purpose is to get category structure with single query.
I sort my table by path and I get category tree.

**sort_order :** Indicates sort order between categories with same level

[image]

When I run query

```
SELECT * FROM category order by path;
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**But result must be as shown below**  because sort_order of Electronic is 1 and this is less than sort_order value of Computer category 2

```
 - ELectronic 
 - - TV 
 - - - LCD 
 - - - - LED LCD 
 - Computer 
 - - Laptop
```

EDIT :

For @adopilot

**Query** : SELECT * FROM category order by level, path;

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: did you try order by level,path ? You can put more then one column in order

Comment: yes I tried it but it doesn't work as ı need :(

Comment: @adopilot I have added result of your query to question

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I am using MySql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, he wants to do a recursive sort (first sort by grand-...-grandparent, then by ... grandparent, then by parent, then by sort_order for those with same parent), putting all the rows with same (top) ancestor in same group.

Comment: OK, then I misread the question. It would be sooo easy with recursive queries...

Comment: @faridmovsumov This could be solved if you materialized not only the path but the sort_order. A kind of materialized order_path.

Comment: @ypercube can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you need to extract the sort order for the root items and make that same order apply to the sub-items in the tree without re-ordering the sub-items.  In Oracle you can do this with a windowing function as follows:

```
SELECT RPAD('- ',Length(Path)-1,'- ') || label, levelx, path, sort_order
   , min(sort_order) OVER (PARTITION BY FirstLevel) Sort_Order2
FROM (
   SELECT id, parent_id, label, levelx, path, sort_order
      , substr(path,2,1) FirstLevel 
   FROM t1 WHERE Label IS NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY Sort_Order2, Path;
```

I don't know if you can do something like that in MYSQL, so here is a version using a GROUP BY and self join that works in MySQL 5.5.28.

```
SELECT Label
FROM T1 a
JOIN
   (SELECT SUBSTR(Path,2,1) FirstLevel, MIN(Sort_Order) FirstSort FROM T1 
      WHERE Label IS NOT NULL GROUP BY SUBSTR(Path,2,1)) b
   ON substr(a.Path,2,1) = b.FirstLevel
ORDER BY FirstSort, Path;
```

[(SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/174ef/2)

Comment: What an imagination. You got the ordering. Indentation is just a formality from here. +1 !!!

Comment: I did the ordering on the Oracle version, but didn't know the MySQL syntax to do it for that version.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that using Sort Order in any combination just to accommodate a particular level is just not going to cut it in this instance. I believe what you are looking for is an in-order tree traversal.

I have already written posts on how to do pre-order tree traversal

- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)
- `Oct 24, 2011` : [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)

You should be able to pull this off using `id`,`parent_id`,`sort_order` and `path`.

In fact, let me describe a pseudo-algorithm.

- DATA STRUCTURE : Stack
- STACK OPERATIONS

  - Push (Place New Data on Top of Stack)
  - Pop (Remove Data From Top of Stack)
- ALGORITHM START : Push top `parent_id` (0)
- LOOP

  - Pop `parent_id` from the Stack
  - Display label of `parent_id` indented based on `level`
  - Retrieve All `id` values from `parent_id` whose status = 1
  - Push All Retrieved `id` values by `sort_order` DESC, path DESC into the Stack
- END LOOP when Stack is Empty after Pop with nothing to Push

I will leave it to you write the Stored Procedures for handling a Stack.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will try to adopt your examples to my problem.