# Get data from two tables with recursive relationships

Tags: mysql, join, php

I have a MySQL 5.1 DB, being used behind a PHP application to track permissions and other items that need to be issued to staff that hold various positions within an org. To track what privileges a position has, I'm using this table:

```
mysql> desc position_privs;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| position     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| priv         | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date_added   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| date_removed | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`position` refers to an `id` column in a `positions` table, and `priv` refers to an `id` column in a `privs` table. Some positions also inherit privileges from other positions, which may in turn inherit from yet another position, etc. I have this table for that:

```
mysql> desc position_inherits;
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| position           | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| inherit_privs_from | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date_added         | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| date_removed       | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the inheritances were always only one level deep, I could do this with a simple `JOIN`, but I'm stumped as to handling positions that inherit from a position, which in turn inherits from another position.

Is there a convenient way of doing this using MySQL, or should I just stick to `SELECT * FROM $table` and doing it in the application code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## BAD NEWS

MySQL does not support recursive data or table structures. Neither does it support recursive SQL.

## GOOD NEWS

There is a hope. I have written some stored functions on how to retrieve hierarchies of data

- `Oct 24, 2011` : [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)
- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)

## CAVEAT

- You would have to implement this against your tables.
- You also need to make sure you are entering data as a Tree and not as a Graph.

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)
  - http://wiki.answers.com/Q/DIFFERENCE_between_GRAPH_and_TREE_IN_DATA_STRUCTURES
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707983/491757
- For any row in the `position_inherits` table that does not have a parent, simply set that row's `inherit_privs_from` to zero(0). That way, you have establish root positions.

Comment: Heh, looks like I've got a bit of reading to do. Much appreciated, looks like this should work for my purpose.