# Packet and N-SubPacket Msql query ( same as catgeory and N sub catgeory )

Tags: mysql, join, mysqli

First of i am PHP Developer , and working on huge project alone .i think i have made many mistake in creating table. and below is one of those.

I am making packet type system when in my **Packet Table** , parent packet ( `id` which is primary key ) and its N -Sub Packet is under (`parent_id`) is stored , below is my table structure :

***Packet_table***

```
id | packet_name | parent_id |
------------------------------
1  |   01        |  0
2  |   02        |  0
3  |   03        |  1
4  |   04        |  1
5  |   05        |  1
6  |   06        |  4
7  |   07        |  4
8  |   08        |  3
9  |   09        |  5
10 |   010       |  2 
........................so on and on with N packets in same table
```

Below is what i have tried *but its not getting* `id` N sub packet detail properly:

```
SELECT p.`packet_name` AS MAIN, s.`packet_name` AS SUB
FROM packet_table s
LEFT JOIN packet_table p ON s.`parent_id` = p.`id`
```

thats as per above table : **id** ( which is primary / auto increment )

id = 1 -> main packet (01) , its sub and  N sub packets are :

01 - > 03,04,05

04 -> 06,07

03 -> 08

05 -> 09

**in short**

```
01 -> 03 -> 08
      04 -> 06 , 07
      05 -> 09
```

its not necessary above design format mysql code .. just simple N sub packet query will do

above is just few but in my case there will be N number of sub packet for each (id).

above packet primary id is used in many other tables , so i will get all information in future ?

**Note :** it can be same as Category and N sub Category type, also please note as said above i don't want query as above explained ( as tree )  .. i just need only mysql query in any format ..

1 } just need is when i search with id=1 then result will give me it all sub packet and it N sub sub packets,

2 } when i search with any sub packet id then it result should give me its sub packet and its all N sub packet and so on and on.. also this sub packet is of which main packet and vise verse.

**UPDATE :** please check below format for query i need some with N Packet

```
Table Format 1 :  thats Main Packet 
+------------+------------+----------+
| Main Pkt   | Sub Packet | COUNT(*) |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 01         | 03         |        1 |
| 01         | 04         |        1 |
| 01         | 05         |        1 |
--------------------------------------
```

**Second :**

```
Table Format 2 :  thats Sub and Its N sub Packet 
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Main Pkt   | Sub Packet | N Sub Packet    |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| 01         | 03         |        08       |
| 01         | 04         |        06       |
| 01         | 04         |        07       |
| 01         | 05         |        09       |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Third :**

```
Table Format 2 :  thats Sub and Its N sub Packet 
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Main Pkt   | Sub Packet | N Sub Packet    |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| 01         | 03         |        08       |
| 01         | 04         |        06       |
| 01         | 04         |        07       |
| 03         | 011        |        014      | -- *****
---------------------------------------------
above ***** : here  03 is actually sub packet of 01  hecene it query will also help me
```

So that 01 - 03 - 011 - 014

Comment: Do you want the whole tree in the output or just one level? (i.e., level 1 = `01`, level 2 = `03,04,05`, level 3 =...)

Comment: hey ypercube, thanks for reply , i want mysql query with N sub packet... means id=1 will have many sub packet and each sub packet will also have it sub packet ...and so on and on.. hence how can achieve that .. in short i want all sub .. sub and n sub packet of id=1 or any sub packet - n subpacket query

Comment: Edit the question and add how you want the table output exactly.

Comment: its not about format , just need mysql query.

Comment: And see similar questions, like: [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query)

Comment: + for link , but need query in php-mysql

Comment: i means not Stored Function , query with mysql/php ..

Comment: Stored functions are still SQL. So it would still be a mysql/php solution (whatever the php means). You can call stored functionsand procedures from PHP, as easy as you can run queries. Why not use them?

Comment: but seriously i am not used to be Stored Function, i mean i havent used it before .. so how to start i dont know .. just placing it my query file will work or need to do some in mysql(phpmyadmin)

Comment: pls check now i have add some table format .. but its few .. but need same for N packets

Comment: hey i have added format ..pls check

Comment: hey any one still here ?