# While Loop - Parent/Child Tree

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, recursive

I'm trying to recursively loop through and return all `child_id`'s that have the root element of `9`.

**The structure:**

```
->9
->->8
->->->17
->->22
->->->11
```

**Parent Child Link Table:**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id | child_id |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         9 |        8 |
|  2 |         8 |       17 |
|  3 |         8 |       33 |
|  4 |         8 |       18 |
|  5 |         9 |       22 |
|  6 |        22 |       11 |
|  7 |        22 |        4 |
|  8 |         3 |        5 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

**Procedure (so far):**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE x INT(11)

SET x = 0;
SET @elements = "";
SET @node = _root_; -- 9
SET @child_count = count_children(@node) -- function returning the child count of @node;
SET @children = get_children(@node); -- function returning the child id's of @node

-- check IF node has children
WHILE x <= @child_count DO
    SET @elements = CONCAT(@elements,x,',');
    SET x = x + 1;
END WHILE
SELECT @elements;

END
```

**Desired Output:** [8,17,33,18,22,11,4]

**Question:** How can I modify my procedure to be able to return all `child_id`'s of the parent?

Comment: So is it just that, you want to return an array of the `child_id` column?

Comment: @NelsonCasanova only child elements who have the parent node of `9`.

Comment: If you are using version 8.0 or 10.2, there are "recursive CTEs" to do tasks like this.  Otherwise, you need to write a look in your app code (or in a Stored Proc) to do the task.

Comment: @RickJames yeah I've been looking at those, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table( id int, parent_id int,child_id int)
insert into @t values
(1 , 9 ,  8 ),(2 , 8 , 17 )
,(3 , 8 , 33 ),(4 , 8 , 18 )
,(5 , 9 , 22 ),(6 ,22 , 11 )
,(7 ,22 ,  4 ),(8 , 3 ,  5 )

declare @parentinput int=9

select t.* from @t t
left join @t t1
on t.child_id=t1.parent_id
where t.parent_id=@parentinput

union 
select t1.* from @t t
left join @t t1
on t.child_id=t1.parent_id
where t.parent_id=@parentinput
```

Comment: If I'm correct, this works with the data as given, but only allows for three levels: parent, child, and grandchild. No specific limit on the number of levels deep the parent-child relationships can go was specified, so I'm not sure that meets the OP's needs.