# SELECT query to read recursive relationship table

Tags: mysql, recursive

I have below MySQL database table which has a recursive relationship. A hospital maybe managed by another main hospital in this scenario. I have a difficult time trying to retrieve all data with name of the hospital which manages another hospital.

[image]

Some expert help would be much helpful for me.
Thanks.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: Is B H Gampola 'managed by' MSD?  That is, the full chain needs to be walked through, not just one level?  In MySQL 8.0 it is relatively easy with a "recursive CTE"; before that, it is messier.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query