# Fetch all parents from child id

Tags: mysql, recursive

I created a table with name "**vegs**" and inserted values just like this.

```
    id  name            parent
--------------------------------------
    1   fruits          0
    2   Apple           1
    3   Orange          1
    4   Grape           1
    5   Green Apple     2
    6   Red Apple       2
```

I want to recursively fetch all parents of the child  "**6**".

Comment: This might be helpful. Found it on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query-recursive-query

Answer (score 5):

Recursive queries cannot be done with pure SQL when it comes to MySQL.

I have written posts on how to use Stored Procedures to accomplish this

- `Oct 24, 2011` : [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)
- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)
- `Jul 15, 2013` : [Get top most parent by nth child id?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/get-top-most-parent-by-nth-child-id/46398#46398)

Give them a Try !!!

**NOTE** : This post, originally `May 24, 2014`, predates [MySQL 8.0, which now has CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).