# MySQL: How to fetch nth level child menus of a parent menu

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have a menu which is parent of multiple menu items and each child menu has their own child menus. This pattern is continued till 5-6 vertical hierarchy level.
I don't want to write a query which contains nth level subquery as below:

`select id from jos_menu where parent in(select id from jos_menu where parent in(select id from jos_menu  where parent=385 and published=1))`

Also, I don't want to write a script for this. There should be something in MySQL to fetch such result.

Can someone guide me about how can I achieve my result in the best way?

Comment: There are several models to store hierarchical data, depending on the rest of the operations that you intend to do on that dataset. I would recommend having a look at http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data from @BillKarwin , a regular of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

A long, long time ago (Oct 24, 2011), in a galaxy far away, someone boldly asked

[Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes)

In my answer to that post, I wrote [three stored procedures](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/877) to find specific relationships

- `GetParentIDByID`
- `GetAncestry`
- `GetFamilyTree`

If you use the code in `GetFamilyTree`, just pick the nth member of the output.

I have referred others to that post

- `Jan 31, 2014` : [Recursive Query in MySQL using stored proceedure and CURSOR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57934/recursive-query-in-mysql-using-stored-proceedure-and-cursor/58024#58024)
- `Jul 11, 2013` : [Recursive self joins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins/46155#46155)
- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking to see if MySQL supports CTE's (Common Table Expressions) I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159