# sql or hql query to find all parents of a particular record

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sql-developer, cte

[image]

---

I need a sql or hql query to find all parents of a particular record, that should work in oracle as well as mysql, for eg if I have the id: 201, the parents would be: 188, 187, 1.
any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: You will need to use recursive query and then aggregate your results into array, or concatenate in some text column by appending values to it on each call

Comment: MySQL has not implemented (recursive or not) CTEs so it would be probably impossible to find a solution that works in both MySQL and Oracle with your current design. If you move from the Adjacency List model to another model (like Closure table), you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Oct 24, 2011, I wrote some Stored Functions to perform Ancestor and Descendant traversals ([Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161) ). From my post, you would use `GetAncestry`. From your data,  the code in `GetAncestry` will traverse until it sees `-1` as a parent id. No changes in the algorithm are needed except to change `parent_id` to `parent`.

For the sake of example, let's suppose the table is called `mydb.mytable`

## GetAncestry Code

```
USE mydb
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetAncestry` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;
    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(parent,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT parent FROM mytable WHERE id = ch) A;
        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Once you create this stored procedure, you would call the function as follows:

```
USE mydb
SELECT GetAncestry(201);
```

Let's test that out

## Sample Data Based On Your Question

```
drop database if exists mydb;
create database mydb;
use mydb
create table mytable
(id int not null,
name varchar(20),
parent int default -1,
primary key (id));
insert into mytable values
(1,'ROOT',-1),(162,'ROOT',1),(163,'ROOT',1),(164,'ROOT',1),
(165,'ROOT',1),(166,'ROOT',1),(167,'ROOT',1),(168,'ROOT',1),
(169,'ROOT',1),(170,'ROOT',1),(171,'ROOT',1),(172,'ROOT',1),
(173,'ROOT',1),(174,'ROOT',1),(175,'ROOT',1),(176,'ROOT',1),
(177,'ROOT',1),(178,'ROOT',1),(179,'ROOT',1),(180,'ROOT',1),
(181,'ROOT',1),(182,'ROOT',1),(183,'ROOT',1),(184,'ROOT',1),
(185,'ROOT',184),(186,'ROOT',1),(187,'ROOT',1),(188,'ROOT',187),
(201,'ROOT',188),(202,'ROOT',201),(203,'ROOT',202);
```

## Load Sample Data

```
mysql> drop database if exists mydb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mydb
Database changed
mysql> create table mytable
    -> (id int not null,
    -> name varchar(20),
    -> parent int default -1,
    -> primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values
    -> (1,'ROOT',-1),(162,'ROOT',1),(163,'ROOT',1),(164,'ROOT',1),
    -> (165,'ROOT',1),(166,'ROOT',1),(167,'ROOT',1),(168,'ROOT',1),
    -> (169,'ROOT',1),(170,'ROOT',1),(171,'ROOT',1),(172,'ROOT',1),
    -> (173,'ROOT',1),(174,'ROOT',1),(175,'ROOT',1),(176,'ROOT',1),
    -> (177,'ROOT',1),(178,'ROOT',1),(179,'ROOT',1),(180,'ROOT',1),
    -> (181,'ROOT',1),(182,'ROOT',1),(183,'ROOT',1),(184,'ROOT',1),
    -> (185,'ROOT',184),(186,'ROOT',1),(187,'ROOT',1),(188,'ROOT',187),
    -> (201,'ROOT',188),(202,'ROOT',201),(203,'ROOT',202);
Query OK, 31 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 31  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

## Create the Stored Function

```
mysql> USE mydb
Database changed
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetAncestry` $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `GetAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
    -> DETERMINISTIC
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    ->     DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    ->     DECLARE ch INT;
    ->
    ->     SET rv = '';
    ->     SET cm = '';
    ->     SET ch = GivenID;
    ->     WHILE ch > 0 DO
    ->         SELECT IFNULL(parent,-1) INTO ch FROM
    ->         (SELECT parent FROM mytable WHERE id = ch) A;
    ->         IF ch > 0 THEN
    ->             SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
    ->             SET cm = ',';
    ->         END IF;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->     RETURN rv;
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

## Call GetAncestry

```
mysql> SELECT GetAncestry(201);
+------------------+
| GetAncestry(201) |
+------------------+
| 188,187,1        |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Only one thing left to do...

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

[**I have discussed using GetAncestry in the DBA StackExchange many times**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20GetAncestry)

Please note that this is a MySQL-specific answer. Please read PL/SQL Documentation if you wish to implement the algorithm in a PL/SQL block or a Stored Procedure.