# How can I count all children & grandchildren until the 7th level?

Tags: mysql, recursive

I have 3 tables right now

```
 1. members
 2. members_parents
 3. members_status
```

How can i count the children & grandchildren until to the depth level and separate the `count()` for the status 0 = free and 1 = subscriber

```
table: members - list all the records of members
table: members_parents - list of members & the parent member
table: members_status - list the members & parents status where 0 or 1
```

tbl_members_parents:

```
id   member     parent
1    10000      NULL
2    10001      10000
3    10002      10001
```

and so on ...

How can i count the child & grandchildren until to the 7th level of grand children ?

Thank You

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: truth is i haven't tried anything.. im just finding and asking solutions in web, im just new in php... sorry :(

Comment: Well, the best you can do is edit your question and add your `CREATE TABLE` statements and some test data from each one, and, welcome to dba.SE.

Comment: A recursive CTE can be thought of as a variable number of joins. In your case there is an upper limit on the number of joins, so you can just do a left self join 6 times to build the tree.

Comment: You can use `lft` and `rgt` as two fields to manage whole tree structure fast and traversal and easy way : please check [Link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) OR [Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) form more information.

Answer (score 2):

I have bad news and good news

## BAD NEWS

MySQL does not support [recursive CTE queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL)

Like @RickJames, I don't have the energy to write it for you

## GOOD NEWS

Once upon a time, I did have the energy and time to write stuff like this

Here are my posts I have written discussing Stored Procedures and Recursive Queries

- `Oct 24, 2011` : [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)
- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)
- `Jul 11, 2013` : [Recursive self joins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins/46155#46155)
- `Jan 31, 2014` : [Recursive Query in MySQL using stored proceedure and CURSOR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57934/recursive-query-in-mysql-using-stored-proceedure-and-cursor/58024#58024)
- `Nov 28, 2014` : [Implement a Parent-Level Count in Binary Search Tree](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83889/implement-a-parent-level-count-in-binary-search-tree/83893#83893)

From the [first link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161), I addressed this table structure

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testdb`.`observations` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `parent_id` INT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

that was holding this data

[image: PictureFromOtherPost]

I made three Stored Procedures centered around them

- GetParentIDByID
- GetAncestry
- GetFamilyTree

What's interesting about the code is that I do not use recursion. I use a String as a comma-separated list of node IDs and process it like a queue. This technique is known as [PreOrder Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_2) except each tree node can have more than two children.

## SUGGESTION

What you need to do is [read the code from that first post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161) and apply it with your fields and keys in mind.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: If you want the code written for you, I am sure @RickJames or I can do so (we charge by the hour ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

It will required a recursive Stored Procedure.  Sorry, I don't have the energy to write it for you.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth ; perhaps you can use `max_sp_recursion_depth=7` to automatically stop at that depth.  In any case, you need to set it, since recursion is disabled by default.